# How do I match sentence punctuations with exceptions?

Tags: regex

I am trying everything, but I just can't figure it out how to write correct regex.

For example I have a few sentences:

```
I want a car, bike etc. or watching football. Bring me money!<br><br>
```

Then I have exceptions:

```
etc\.
imho\.
```

And separators:

```
\.
\!
```

And I need to match those separators, but exclude exceptions. In sentences written above I need to match the end of the sentence (dot at the end and ! at the end), but I should not match etc.

I want a car, bike etc. or watching football. Bring me money! 
-> Should be 2 sentences:
I want a car, bike etc. or watching football
Bring me money

Now I am using only firstseparator|secondseparator|... as regex so my result is
 ->
3 sentences:
I want a car, bike etc
or watching football
Bring me money!

Comment: Could you make your question clearer? It's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I need to match end of the sentence (but the end is decided by list of separators not just standard punctuation) but I must not match those word written in list of exceptions.

Comment: So are you saying that if you had "Sentence etc\." it should not match, but "Sentence\." should match?  Should "Sentence." match?

Comment: This is what I have now: http://regex101.com/r/eL8yA7 but dot near etc should not be matched.

\. actually means escaped dot

Comment: You could use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), if your regex flavor supports it, e.g. `(?<!etc|imho)[.!?]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookbehind to ensure you match `.` as long it is not preceded by an exception word. Try `(?<!etc)\.`

Comment: Jonny 5, you beat me by a minute!

Comment: Santiago this will work if in exceptions will be etc, but there is etc\.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, 1403588. I tested the regex with the negative lookbehind and it fits your requirements.

`str => "I want a car, bike etc. or watching football. Bring me money!"`
`str.scan /(?<!etc)\./ => ["."]`
`str.scan /\./ => [".", "."]`

Comment: Look at exceptions list. There is etc\. so regex is then str.scan /(?<!etc\.)\./ => not working good anymore. Anyway I fixed problem with this regex (\w(etc\.|imho\.|[^\.\!\?])+ which match whole sentence (on which i make other types of transformations) instead of only delimiter (at first I suppose to split input string using delimiter).

Comment: Thing is, if your separator is `.` and `etc.` is one of your exceptions, your regex should read "match any dot, as long as it is not preceded by the word etc". If you replace what is in the negative lookbehind by `etc.`, you are saying "match any dot, as long as it nos not preceded by etc.", which is not what you want.